# Columns ID, update, project. I want a pie chart where there are percentages of updates of different projects in database for particular employee

Tags: sql, ssms

I have used this query but it gives me percentage of only single project.

```
SELECT 
    100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN Proj = 'abc' AND ID = '101' THEN Update END) /
       COUNT(CASE WHEN ID = '101' THEN proj END) AS percentage 
FROM Updates;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired rsults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little unclear what you want.  If you want the proportion *within* a project:

```
SELECT Proj,
       AVG(CASE WHEN ID = '101' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0 END) as percentage
FROM Updates
GROUP BY Proj;
```

If you want the proportion over *all* projects:

```
SELECT Proj,
       COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as percentage
FROM Updates
WHERE ID = 101
GROUP BY Proj;
```